# How do I Instantiate Instances of a Class That Is In Another Project Within My Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two projects within my solution called HelpDeskBusinessUserObjects and HelpDeskBusinessDataObjects. I am trying to create an instance of a class called EmployeeBusinessData in side the UserObjects project but so far I've had no luck. I've tried adding a reference to HelpDeskBusinessDataObjects from HelpDeskBusinessUserObjects but that hasn't worked either. What I want to be able to do is:

```
EmployeeBusinessData empData = new EmployeeBusinessData();
```

And do this within the HelpDeskBusinessUserObjects.

Comment: What error do you get? How did you add the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post the error response.

Also after adding the dll of HelpDeskBusinessDataObjects to HelpDeskBusinessUserObjects, in your class file did you include

```
using HelpDeskBusinessDataObjects
```

Comment: Im still new to using VB and C# so this was what I was missing. A simple import. Thank you so much!